# Unable to access fireabse databse in signInWithEmailAndPassword task.isSuccessfull

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to access users database right after user is authenticated but Its always says

> Listen at /users failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        if(user!=null){
                            if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Check your inbox to verify email address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                onLoginFailed();
                            }else{
                                checkUserType();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        onLoginFailed();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            onLoginFailed();
        }
    });

public boolean checkUserType(){
    boolUserType = false;
    Query query1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
            .orderByKey()
            .equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    query1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                String prefUserKey = sharedPreferences.getString("userKey",null);
                String userKey = user.getUser_key();
                if(prefUserKey==userKey){
                    boolUserType =  true;
                }
                else{
                    boolUserType =  false;
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            boolUserType = false;
        }
    });
    return boolUserType;
}
```

Comment: What if you try to change the rules of database to: `".read": true,
    ".write": true` will you still get the same error?

Comment: Hi @Yupi, following are the database rules
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
      },
        ".read": "auth != null",
    },
      
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".read": "auth != null",
    
  }
}

I only want to access the database once user is authenticated

Comment: Yes I undrestand that you can change back to your desired rules but this way you will eliminate for example issue with `google-services.json` file.

Comment: I guess that will be a temporary solution.

Comment: You didn't understand just change the rules to make test that there is no issue with `google-services.json` file and you can change the rules again.

Comment: @Yupi I am able to access database on other activites but I am unable to access the database on the same activity.

Comment: Can you update code with `Logcat` exception

Comment: ur not able to access on this activity? but on other activities you can write?@AkmalRasool

Comment: Yes @PeterHaddad I am not able to access on this activity but I am able to access this on other activities

Comment: yes because of the rules

Comment: Yes @PeterHaddad rules says u can only access when you are authenticated and as u can see i am trying to access database(in task.issuccessfull) once its authenticated with valid email and pwd.

Comment: to which line does the error refer to?

Comment: When ever the excution reach at this line of code
Query query1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
            .orderByKey()
            .equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
@PeterHaddad

Comment: @AkmalRasool  Im not sure. As logically if he enters that method it means the user is authenticated according to your code. Maybe add like a progress dialog with a timer and see if he can access it after some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164432/discussion-between-akmal-rasool-and-peter-haddad).